# to directly download txt file?

Tags: firefox, text-files

How to configure Firefox such that whenever a link to a txt file is clicked, this txt file will directly got downloaded to the local file system, without asking user what you want to do with the file and where you want to save this file to?

It seems that in the Firefox's Application Panel, there is no entry for txt file although I've  already clicked a link to a txt file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you press ALT while you click on the link it should just save the link, so in your case it will just save the .txt file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can this "ALT" press be done programmatically in Firefox extension?